# Why does the distributive law not apply to $\,2(2.49\cdot 10^8)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does the distributive law not apply here?
$$2(2.49\cdot 10^8)$$

The solving steps given to me was to multiply 2 with 2.49 **only**. The 10^8 was neglected by the 2, however, this contrasts to the distributive law. So I'm a bit confused on how to proceed further with this.

Comment: The distributive law you have in mind is, I expect, $a\times (b+c)=a\times b +a\times c$.  That's not the situation you have.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distributive law says that if $a,b,c$ are real numbers, then $a\cdot(b+c)= a\cdot b + a\cdot c$.

Your situation is not one to which the distributive law would apply, since there is no summation. The law that **does** apply to your situation is the associativity law, which states that $a\cdot (b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c$.

---

In other words, associativity can be applied by setting $a=2, b=2.49, c=10^8$, and substituting these into the general statement, which yields $$2\cdot (2.49\cdot 10^8) = (2\cdot 2.49)\cdot 10^8 = 4.98\cdot 10^8.$$

There is no substitution of $a,b,c$ that you can make in which the distributivity law would tell you something about the original expression.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment 